# OpenGL Glut procedure entry point not found in glut32.dll

Tags: c++, opengl, dll, glut

I have a Glut application for a homework, on my first assignment, i've set up the environment, i have moved glut32.dll into my windows/system and windows/system 32. And included the .lib and the .h in the visual studio environment.

I'm using visual studio 2013, with windows 7.

My first assigment was easy i had to just draw some simple lines, dots, some polygons., it worked no problem. After 2 weeks i had another assignment and i opened my first one and run it   and i got a uhly error, that the procedure entry point is not located in the glut32.dll. I didn't change anything, didn't download any knew version. Practically done nothing to change it's behavior, annd i got this error. I looked up on google for answers, and i tried to see what functions does the .dll exports, and it seems that te .dll exports the function i used, _glCreateWindowExit(something like this) but it still gives me the error. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Stupid question on my part, but did you try cleaning the project? (Build on menu bar -> clean solution)

Comment: Clean rebuild a lot of times.